# how to get an index of each partition when using RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, indexing, rdd

I am new in spark and scala. Is there a way in Spark to get the Partition ID/No from
`RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex` where it defined as follows :

```
def randomint(index: Int, iter: Iterator[T]) : Iterator[(Int, T)]={
...
}
self.mapPartitionsWithIndex(randomint).partitionBy(new randParti(nump)).values
```

Answer (score 0):

Your naming might be confusing, but the `index` variable in the `randomint` function does contain what you are looking for: the partition no.